# Gitlab: webhook: merge request event

Tags: gitlab

I have created a webhook in gitlab on a merge request event. And to see what was in the event, I used the ruby example in the docs.

Then I use the test button.

Looking at the json body, I notice that the object kind is "push", even though this is a Merge Request Event. I have other webhooks which are Push events.

The docs for gitlab webhooks show a merge request as having an object kind field of "merge_request". Of course the docs could be out of date.

Any ideas why I appear to be getting push data on a merge request event?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is a feature in gitlab. When testing a webhook, it only sends a push event, even if the webhook fires on other events.